# Finding all integer solutions of the following inequality $\bigg| \sqrt[3]{2}-\frac{p}{q} \bigg | <\frac{1}{q^{5/2}}$

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory, wolfram-alpha-queries

I want to find  *integer solutions* of the following inequality by using *Mathematica*

$$\bigg| \sqrt[3]{2}-\frac{p}{q} \bigg | <\frac{1}{q^{5/2}}$$

```
Reduce[Abs[Surd[2, 3] - p/q] < 1/q^(5/2), {p, q}, Integers] //ToRadicals // TraditionalForm
```

but there is a strange result

[image]

I also tried `FindInstance` ***but there is the only one solution***

```
FindInstance[Abs[Surd[2, 3] - p/q] < 1/q^(5/2), {p, q}, Integers, 2]
```

[image]

**There are 3 solutions according the** [**Wolfram Alpha**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Abs%5BSurd%5B2,+3%5D+-+p%2Fq%5D+%3C+1%2Fq%5E2.5)

[image]

but...

```
WolframAlpha["Abs[Surd[2,3]-p/q]<1/q^2.5)", {{"IntegerSolution"}, "Content"}]
```

> {}

It's still not working..

I tried "***Open Code***" in WolframAlpha but it didn't help me.

what's going on here? :)

Comment: If you don't mind specifying a range of integers to search (which, understandably, you probably do) you could use a region: `reg = ImplicitRegion[Abs[Surd[2, 3] - p/q] < 1/q^(5/2), {{p, 1, 5}, {q, 1, 5}}];` and then `Reduce[Element[{p, q}, reg], {p, q}, Integers]` gives you the desired output.

Comment: A graphical solution is possible with `Show[Graphics[{LightGray, Table[Point[{i, j}], {i, 0, 6}, {j, 0, 6}]},
   Axes -> True], 
 RegionPlot[Abs[Surd[2, 3] q - p] < 1/q^(3/2), {p, 0, 6}, {q, 0, 6}, 
  Frame -> True], 
 Graphics[{Red, Point[{1, 1}], Point[{2, 1}], Point[{5, 4}]}, 
  Axes -> True]]` to make yourself shure this are all solutions of integer pairs.

Answer (score 4):

See [KennyColnago](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153786/unexpected-behaviour-with-findinstance) answer.

```
Union[Flatten[
Select[Table[
Quiet[FindInstance[Abs[Surd[2, 3] - p/q] < 1/q^(5/2), {p, q}, 
Integers, 2, RandomSeed -> k]], {k, 1, 200}], 
Head[#] =!= FindInstance &], 1]]

(* {{p -> 1, q -> 1}, {p -> 2, q -> 1}, {p -> 5, q -> 4}} *)
```

Comment: Too slow.......